# How to reshape dataframe to create stacked bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
    date        product quantity
0   2021-03-01  A       55
1   2021-03-01  B       43
2   2021-04-01  A       55
2   2021-04-01  B       46
2   2021-05-01  C       10...
```

I want to crate the following shape:

```
    date        product quantity_A  quantity_B quantity_C ..quantity_n
0   2021-03-01  A       55          43         0            0
2   2021-04-01  A       55          46         0            0
2   2021-05-01  C       0           0          10           0
```

So, I need the dataframe index to be a unique date and encode my product-quantity pairs, so that for each month, I have all product quantities in one row.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's at most one `quantity` for each `product` per `date` then you could use `.pivot`:

```py
result = (
    df.pivot(values="quantity", index="date", columns="product")
    .fillna(0).astype("int")
    .rename(columns=lambda c: f"quantity_{c}")
)
```

Result:

```
product     quantity_A  quantity_B  quantity_C
date                                          
2021-03-01          55          43           0
2021-04-01          55          46           0
2021-05-01           0           0          10
```

If that's not the case then you could use `.pivot_table` with `sum` as aggregation function instead:

```py
result = (
    df.pivot_table(
        values="quantity", index="date", columns="product",
        aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0
    )
    .rename(columns=lambda c: f"quantity_{c}")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method is `DataFrame.unstack`.
First of all, set `date` and `product` as df's **secondary index**:

```py
df = df.set_index(['date', 'product']).quantity
```

Then, use `unstack` to convect df to DataFrame:

```py
df = df.unstack()
df = df.fillna(0)
print(df)
"""
               A     B     C
date                        
2021-03-01  55.0  43.0   0.0
2021-04-01  55.0  46.0   0.0
2021-05-01   0.0   0.0  10.0
"""
```

---

Or with for loop, just use `DataFrame.groupby` and `Series.unique` to solve you problem.
Code like this:

```py
# df is your raw input
columns  = ['quantity_%s' % i for i in df['product'].unique()]

# init ans dataframe
ans = pd.DataFrame(
    index = df['date'].unique(),
    columns = columns
)
# set default value to 0
ans = ans.fillna(0)

# use groupby to classify product
for k, v in df.groupby('date'):
    for i, j in v.iterrows():
        ans.loc[k]['quantity_%s' % j['product']] = j['quantity']
```

Then output blow:

```py
            quantity_A  quantity_B  quantity_C
2021-03-01          55          43           0
2021-04-01          55          46           0
2021-05-01           0           0          10
```

By the way, do not use `prodcut` as name of columns, because it is confused with the function of `DataFrame.product`.

Comment: This solution is not fast due to the loop. It broke my code as I have millions of rows. Also, how do you store the output? Could you help please?

Comment: I have optimized `for loop` with `DataFrame.unstack`, which is fast.